# Translating to Bash Command

Tags: bash

So for a project for school I had to install the DPJ extension to the Java language. I downloaded and unpacked a tarball containing the files, and then was told to run the following:

```
setenv DPJ_ROOT ${Home}/dpjbin

setenv PATH ${PATH}:${DPJ_ROOT}/Implementation/bin
```

How do I do these commands using bash? I know I have to open up the /etc/profile file and add 2 lines (or for the PATH one do I just append something to the top line of the file after a colon?). Any help in how to do this would be appreciated. If it helps I run Ubuntu 14.04 on Virtualbox (and have little to no experience)

Answer (score 0):

```
export DPJ_ROOT="$Home/dpjbin"
PATH+=":${DPJ_ROOT}/Implementation/bin"
```

`PATH` is already exported, so you don't have to do that.

Comment: is `$Home` supposed to be your home directory? if yes, use `$HOME`

Comment: When I go to compile the examples I get an error saying the make command is not found. Is this error-related to the PATH? And any idea what I should do?

Comment: You probably need to `apt-get install make`

Comment: That still didn't work. Could it being anything else?

Comment: "didn't work" is the worst possible problem description. Provide more details about exactly what you're doing and exactly what you're seeing.